# What are the default separator for string interpolation?

Tags: julia

It seems `",", "$", "/"` all serve as a separator, but `"_"` not.

```
x = "1"
"$x,x", "$x$x", "$x/1", "$x_1"
```

Is there any doc about this?

Comment: If you want to be sure that the interpolation is terminated, simply use ( ) around the name, i.e. "$(myname)".  This can be important if the identifier is followed by some Unicode characters, which could at some point be change to be allowed as identifier characters in the parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [doc says](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/5de52cf9c9343cfcf50be4c7c736290d3f985961/doc/manual/strings.rst#interpolation):

> The shortest complete expression after the $ is taken as the expression whose value is to be interpolated into the string

The internal workings are explained in the [github issue #455](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/455) which could be summarised by:

> The way string interpolation works is actually entirely defined in Julia. What happens is that the parser (in FemtoLisp) scans the code and finds a string literal, delimited by double quotes. If it finds no unescaped $ in the string, it just creates a string literal itself — ASCIIString or UTF8String depending on the content of the string. On the other hand, if the string has an unescaped $, it punts and hands the interpretation of the string literal to the str julia macro, which generates an expression that constructs the desired strings by concatenating string literals and interpolated values. This is a nice elegant scheme that lets the parser not worry about stuff like interpolation.

I could guess that `#\, #\) #\] #\} #\;` which are `,`, `)`, `]`, `}` and `;` respectively are closing tokens for expressions and `$` is specifying the start of next interpolation.

Comment: This isn't true anymore – the Julia parser actually handles all of the interpolation itself these days. This was the only way to sanely allow things like interpolating expressions which themselves contained string literals. But excellent GitHub archeology :-)

Comment: @StefanKarpinski Could you edit my reply to provide the up-to-date reply ?

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is because x_1 is a valid variable name in Julia, so it is trying to insert the value of that variable into the string.